# How do I launch an external application from the browser like Telegram url links?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, alert, telegram

I am trying to recreate the following application launch with telegram when one visits the telegram user profile page. Example: https://t.me/username1

When the page is loaded, it gives an alert box to open the telegram app. How do I recreate this as a URL link on a webpage? Also how are they doing this on page load and where is it in the source code so I can see it?

Comment: The app must include a browser extension that does this, you can't do it from regular JavaScript.

Comment: Isn't this just a special URL handler that launches the telegram app?

Comment: And how do you think URL handlers get installed?

Answer (score 2):

Use `tg` just like you use `mailto`

```
tg://resolve?domain=username1
```

```html
<a href="tg://resolve?domain=username1">Message me!</a>
```

---

To launch it page load, just use the standard [DOMContentLoaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery) and redirect the browser;

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  window.location.href = "tg://resolve?domain=username1";
});
```

---

I've searched quite some time to find any documentation, there is one [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Telegram/comments/933n0a/where_to_get_info_about_tg_links/) from 1 year ago, but they only shared the ['source file'](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/a919737f6ef98b56cd7db41577ecfc269a60f444/Telegram/SourceFiles/core/click_handler_types.cpp#L61).